# Is there a mechanism to force express redirect to use host paths?

Tags: node.js, express, redirect, serverless

I have the following code snippet made with express js

```
import serverless from 'serverless-http'
import express from 'express';

const app = express();
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());


app.get('/api/info', (req, res) => {
  res.send({ application: 'sample-app', version: '1.0' });
});
app.get('/jump', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('/api/info');
});
app.get('/explicit-jump', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('/dev/api/info');
});
app.post('/api/v1/getback', (req, res) => {
  res.send({ ...req.body });
});

export default serverless(app)
```

If I deploy that code with serverless probably I will get an endpoint like `https://my-api.some-region.amazonaws.com/dev/`

Now if I try to reach the endpoint that redirect without the '/dev' path (`/jump`), I will get forbidden because is trying to reach `https://my-api.some-region.amazonaws.com/api/info`.
The one that set the path explicitly (`/explicit-jump`) works fine.

Fixing this single case is easy but I'm in the context of using an external app boilerplate (shopify express app) that has an incredible amount of redirects, really a high number.

I tried using a middleware that rewrites the urls when redirects:

```
  app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const redirector = res.redirect
    res.redirect = function (url) {
      console.log('CHANGING: ' + url);
      url = url.replace('/api', '/dev/api')
      console.log('TO: ' + url);
      redirector.call(this, url)
    }
    next()
  })
```

But I have the feeling that this is a brute force idea and actually it worked only in some occasions, somehow there are still redirects that goes to the base url ignoring the '/dev' path.

Is there a way I could fix this in a reasonable way so all redirects use the host in where the function is running?

Comment: There are other methods for redirecting than `res.redirect`, for example, sending an HTML form and auto-submitting it with Javascript. Does that occur in your case?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen yes that is also the case. The initial project also contains endpoints that render html with embedded js that get executed automatically. In that case the redirects are done in two fashions, one using an external js function imported in the html and the classical location.href change ```window.location.href = '/api/auth?shop=${shop}';``` . This redirect fail for the same reason, so I'm arriving to the point of manually adjust all redirect types because one solution approach isn't enough.